# Is true that $L_1 = \{01^*0\}$ is $m$-complete in the class of decidable languages?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions

**Question:**

> Is true that $L_1 = \{01^*0\}$ is $m$-complete in the class of
>   decidable languages?
>
> $L_1$ is defined as:
>
> $$L_1 = \{01^*0\} := \{01^n0: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

**Definition of a $m$-complete language:**

> A language $L^*$ is $m$-complete in the class of decidable language,
>   if for any decidable language $L$ we have that $L \leq_m L^*$ (that
>   is, $L$ reduces to $L^*$).

I'm really new in this realm, so I'm quite lost about how to tackle this exercise.

I'm not sure if my approach is correct but I was trying to prove that the statement *is not true* by using a reduction from the Busy Beaver Function to $L_1$ (then, from this reduction and from $L_1$ being decidable we would have that BB problem is decidable, which is not possible).

Let $A$ be the algorithm deciding $L_1$ and $w \in L_1$ a word with $|w| = m$ ones. Now when running $A$ on $w \in L_1$ we keep track of the number of steps $t$ it made just before halting. Since $t = m|\Gamma|^m|Q|$, where $\Gamma$ is the set of tape symbols and $Q$ is the set of states. From here we can find the number $|Q|$ of states required for printing $|w| = m$ ones...

I stopped here because I feel there is already something wrong.

First, even is we find that number $|Q|$ for which $A$ performed $t$ steps before $A(w) = \text{Accept}$, that does not necessarily mean that $|w| = m$ ones could have been achieved with a TM with lesser number of states. Second, ''knowing'' the numbers of ones I'm determining the numbers of states and not the other way around, which is as $BB$ is defined.

Another alternative I was exploring was, on input $w$, to run all TM's $T_1, ... T_n$, that return $|w| = m$ ones. Then we record the input $w$ and the description of the machine $T_i,\ (i \in [1,n])$, that had the least number of states. If we do this $\forall w \in L_1$, we end up with a UTM $T'$, such that:

$$T' = \{ \langle T^*, w\rangle: |Q|_{T^*} = \mathrm{min}(|Q|_{T_1}, ..., |Q|_{T_n}\ \text{}\}$$

Then clearly $T'$ decides $L_1$ (just have to run it on input $w \in L_1$) and at the same time allows us to compute $BB(n)$ for a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (since $n$ is encoded in the description of $T^*$).

Probably here there are some flaws in my reasoning, but in this case, do I have to wait that, on input $w$, all those TM's reach a halt or can I assume that the first machine that halted is the one with the least number of states?

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach can't succeed. You're asked whether every decidable language reduces to $L_1$ but your approach is to try to show that some undecidable language doesn't reduce to it. That would show nothing about decidable languages.

But are you sure that your definition is correct? Every language except $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$ is $m$-complete by the definition you give.

Comment: I was trying to show that there exist some undecidable language that also reduces to it and therefore $L_1$, as defined above, can't be $m$-complete.

Comment: So what if some undecidable languages reduce to it? The property you're trying to establish is that all decidable languages reduce to $L_1$, not that all languages that reduce to it are decidable.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Are you sure? We are trying to disprove that $L_1$ is $R$-Complete, not that it is $R$-Hard. Hence if we showed that $L_1$ is $RE$-Hard by reducing from the BB problem, then, since $R\subsetneq RE$, we have $L_1\not\in R$, so $L_1$ is not $R$-Complete, but only $R$-Hard. This would be a good approach, if the statement were true, which it is not.

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen I was working from the definition given in the question. That definition requires only that every decidable language is reducible to the language we care about, and it says nothing at all about undecidable languages. For example, the halting language meets this definition. Is that not the normal definition? (Actually, I suspect there may be something wrong with that definition, since it would seem that any language except $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$ is complete by that definition...)

Comment: @DavidRicherby That would be the approach if we wanted to prove that $L_1$ is $R$-Complete. It looks like the OP wants to prove that $L_1$ is *not* $R$-Complete. In that case, I believe the normal approach is to show that $L_1$ is not in $R$ by finding a problem outside $R$ - the OP has found the busy beaver problem - and reducing it to $L_1$. Then $L_1$ may or may not be $R$-Hard, but since it is not in $R$, the goal follows.

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen I'm confused. The question defines a term and asks if a particular language meets that definition. That definition talks only about being able to reduce every decidable language to the one we're interested in. Are you using some other definition instead of the one given in the question? The question calls it "$m$-completeness", but you are talking about "$R$-completeness".

Comment: @DavidRicherby Maybe we are talking about different problems. By the way, is the definition even correct? I think it should say $m$-hard instead of $m$-complete. Other than that, I think we are using the same definition. But I posit that to go beyond the definition and using another result is necessary to prove what the OP wants, or in any case that the approach he suggests is valid. Could we prove that $L_1$ is *not* complete for the set of decidable languages using only the definition given, without employing results about undecidable languages?

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen I'm going by the definition given in the question. Since every nontrivial language is $m$-complete by that definition, I assume that either the definition is wrong, or it's a definition that was made up for the purposes of an exercise.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Ah! :) Then I think this is the confusion: The OP has in  mind the usual definitions of $R$ and $RE$, completeness and hardness, whereas you have adopted the definition he gave in his question. Perhaps Jazz can illuminate? Ah, you have asked him to in an edit to your answer.

Comment: I appreciate your and @LieuweVinkhuijzen 's comments. I have rephrased the question of the problem and the definition of a m-complete language (Sorry if I didn't get the problem across. I'm translating from russian ): ). Hopefully it's much clearer now. From the definition of $L_1$ I was trying to prove that is not $m$-complete. To do so, I assumed that $L_1$ fits the definition of m-complete, tried to come up with an algorithm $T'$ that decides $L_1$, and tried to show that $T'$ computes $BB$, which leads to conclude that $L_1$ is not $m$-complete. Maybe I'm still slipping up on something...

Comment: Ah. Aside of that, to be honest I'm not familiar with the concept of $R$-hard. I've been looking for information about it, but I got somewhat confused about what exactly is. Could one of you give me some reference to have a look at?